# State vector for two traveling or standing waves of slightly different phase and frequency - second quantized

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

The Honeywell trapped ion quantum computer [paper here](https://www.honeywell.com/content/dam/honeywell/files/HQS-QCCD-Demonstration.pdf) rotates qubits in the Bloch sphere by applying a pair of laser beams of slightly different frequency. The phase of the beats determines the azimuthal angle of the rotation axis and the frequency difference - the beat frequency - is matched to the relative frequency between the qubits $(E_+-E_-)/\hbar$.
So we have a traveling wave with an envelope that oscillates according to the beat frequency.

I solved Schrodinger's equation for this case using the interaction Hamiltonian:

$H_i=a_1^\dagger \sigma + \sigma^\dagger a_1+a_2^\dagger \sigma + \sigma^\dagger a_2$ where $\sigma$ moves the qubit from its excited state to its ground state and the a's are annihilation operators for the two radiation modes.

For the initial state, I form the tensor product of two coherent states for the two modes.

This works - when you evolve the state, it rotates about the x axis in the Bloch sphere. My question is this: how do I represent the phase of the beats between the two modes in the initial state?

Comment: Hi! You write: "The phase of the beats" Should this be "beams"?

Comment: There are beat oscillations. It is the phase of the beats.

Answer (score 0):

The phase of a photon state is encoded in the state vector by initializing it with a coherent state, that is an eigenstate of the annihilation operator. The phase is encoded as the complex phase of the eigenvalue of the coherent state.